# Can not load admin url in magento 2 with sample data?

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2 with sample data using command line instructions. I can load the frontend without any problem. But when i load admin url, its getting redirected. Actual admin url: local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/, redirected url: http://local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/http:/index/local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/admin/index/index/key/dc29e0deb12bceefaf5d6b01551063e15e66b94a638e3915bf190b9d5d79743f/. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Can you please give us more information about your environment? Also, how did you install?

Answer (score 0):

`local.magento_2.com` is not a valid domain name, and it is dangerous to use an invalid one.